# why is this query so slow in db2?

Tags: database, performance, db2, database-performance, db2-luw

I am facing performance hit by a query,

```
SELECT PrivilegeID,ContainerDN,RoleContainerDN,ServiceProfile,ServiceDN,
        PrivilegeName,PrivilegeDescription,PrivilegeType,PrivilegeMappingType,
        PrivilegeIdentificationSource,AccessType,PrivilegeMapping,
        PrivilegeOwner,PrivilegeBackupOwner,PrivilegeAdminTeam,
        ProvisioningNotification,DeprovisioningNotification,Status,
        InActivatedByUser,InActivationDate,ISOSR,GroupProfileName 
FROM ITIMUSER.TableA 
WHERE (Status='A' OR Status='P') AND (GroupProfileName IS NULL OR 
        GroupProfileName='ALL' OR (GroupProfileName='PosAixGroupProfile' OR 
        GroupProfileName='PosAixRoleProfile' OR 
        GroupProfileName='PosAixUserAliasProfile')) AND (ServiceDN=? OR 
        ServiceDN='ALL')
```

In some environment this query is taking around 50 seconds to execute. I have got explain plan for this query.
I investigated a bit (whatever I could find out, I am newbie in DB performance engg.) 
I suggested following things,

1. Increase locklist size
2. Increase sortheap size (but not sure how much, I think it should be <= row read)
3. Added index on servicedn and status column.(not helping much)
4. tune the query by removing heavy operators like 'OR' by removing them using 'in'

got bit improvement but still it is costly query.

I apologize for longest question :)
Can you please have a look at this exfmt output and suggest me some more possible tunings?

### Database Context:

```
Parallelism:        None
CPU Speed:      3.542582e-07
Comm Speed:         100
Buffer Pool size:   315392
Sort Heap size:     1574
Database Heap size:     2804
Lock List size:     20000
Maximum Lock List:  60
Average Applications:   1
Locks Available:    768000
```

### Package Context:

```
SQL Type:       Dynamic
Optimization Level:     5
Blocking:       Block All Cursors
Isolation Level:    Cursor Stability
```

---------------- STATEMENT 1  SECTION 201 ----------------
    QUERYNO:        1
    QUERYTAG:       CLP
    Statement Type:     Select
    Updatable:      No
    Deletable:      No
    Query Degree:       1

### Original Statement:

```
SELECT PrivilegeID,ContainerDN,RoleContainerDN,ServiceProfile,ServiceDN,
        PrivilegeName,PrivilegeDescription,PrivilegeType,PrivilegeMappingType,
        PrivilegeIdentificationSource,AccessType,PrivilegeMapping,
        PrivilegeOwner,PrivilegeBackupOwner,PrivilegeAdminTeam,
        ProvisioningNotification,DeprovisioningNotification,Status,
        InActivatedByUser,InActivationDate,ISOSR,GroupProfileName 
FROM ITIMUSER.TableA 
WHERE (Status='A' OR Status='P') AND (GroupProfileName IS NULL OR 
        GroupProfileName='ALL' OR (GroupProfileName='PosAixGroupProfile' OR 
        GroupProfileName='PosAixRoleProfile' OR 
        GroupProfileName='PosAixUserAliasProfile')) AND (ServiceDN=? OR 
        ServiceDN='ALL')
```

### Optimized Statement:

```
SELECT Q6.PRIVILEGEID AS "PRIVILEGEID", Q6.CONTAINERDN AS "CONTAINERDN", 
        Q6.ROLECONTAINERDN AS "ROLECONTAINERDN", Q6.SERVICEPROFILE AS 
        "SERVICEPROFILE", Q6.SERVICEDN AS "SERVICEDN", Q6.PRIVILEGENAME AS 
        "PRIVILEGENAME", Q6.PRIVILEGEDESCRIPTION AS "PRIVILEGEDESCRIPTION", 
        Q6.PRIVILEGETYPE AS "PRIVILEGETYPE", Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPINGTYPE AS 
        "PRIVILEGEMAPPINGTYPE", Q6.PRIVILEGEIDENTIFICATIONSOURCE AS 
        "PRIVILEGEIDENTIFICATIONSOURCE", Q6.ACCESSTYPE AS "ACCESSTYPE", 
        Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPING AS "PRIVILEGEMAPPING", Q6.PRIVILEGEOWNER AS 
        "PRIVILEGEOWNER", Q6.PRIVILEGEBACKUPOWNER AS "PRIVILEGEBACKUPOWNER", 
        Q6.PRIVILEGEADMINTEAM AS "PRIVILEGEADMINTEAM", 
        Q6.PROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION AS "PROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION", 
        Q6.DEPROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION AS "DEPROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION", 
        Q6.STATUS AS "STATUS", Q6.INACTIVATEDBYUSER AS "INACTIVATEDBYUSER", 
        Q6.INACTIVATIONDATE AS "INACTIVATIONDATE", Q6.ISOSR AS "ISOSR", 
        Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME AS "GROUPPROFILENAME" 
FROM ITIMUSER.TableA AS Q6 
WHERE Q6.SERVICEDN IN (:?, 'ALL') AND Q6.STATUS IN ('A', 'P') AND 
        ((Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME IS NULL OR (Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME = 'ALL')) OR 
        (((Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME = 'PosAixGroupProfile') OR 
        (Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME = 'PosAixRoleProfile')) OR (Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME 
        = 'PosAixUserAliasProfile')))
```

### Access Plan:

```
Total Cost:         778.169
Query Degree:       0

                                 Rows 
                                RETURN
                                (   1)
                                 Cost 
                                  I/O 
                                  |
                                24535.8 
                                ^HSJOIN
                                (   2)
                                778.169 
                                647.617 
                     /------------+------------\
                  24859                           2 
                 FETCH                         TBSCAN
                 (   3)                        (   9)
                 772.755                     5.31387e-05 
                 647.617                          0 
             /-----+------\                      |
         30140.5          144068                  2 
         RIDSCN       TABLE: ITIMUSER     TABFNC: SYSIBM  
         (   4)   TableA       GENROW
         115.713            Q6                   Q1
         28.6349 
     /-----+------\
 6.47526           30134 
 SORT             SORT  
 (   5)           (   7)
 7.59396          108.119 
    1             27.6349 
   |                |
 6.47526           30134 
 IXSCAN           IXSCAN
 (   6)           (   8)
 7.59281          89.201 
    1             27.6349 
   |                |
 144068           144068
```

INDEX: ITIMUSER  INDEX: ITIMUSER
  SVCDN_STATUS     SVCDN_STATUS
       Q6               Q6

### Extended Diagnostic Information:

No extended Diagnostic Information for this statement.

### Plan Details:

```
1) RETURN: (Return Result)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      778.169
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        2.19454e+08
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        647.617
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   778.169
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     2.19454e+08
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     647.617
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  778.169
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   649.382

    Arguments:
    ---------
    BLDLEVEL: (Build level)
        DB2 v9.5.0.3 : s090225
    HEAPUSE : (Maximum Statement Heap Usage)
        160 Pages
    STMTHEAP: (Statement heap size)
        6402

    Input Streams:
    -------------
        12) From Operator #2

            Estimated number of rows:   24535.8
            Number of columns:      22
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q7.GROUPPROFILENAME+Q7.ISOSR
            +Q7.INACTIVATIONDATE+Q7.INACTIVATEDBYUSER
            +Q7.STATUS+Q7.DEPROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q7.PROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEADMINTEAM+Q7.PRIVILEGEBACKUPOWNER
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEOWNER+Q7.PRIVILEGEMAPPING
            +Q7.ACCESSTYPE
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEIDENTIFICATIONSOURCE
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEMAPPINGTYPE+Q7.PRIVILEGETYPE
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEDESCRIPTION+Q7.PRIVILEGENAME
            +Q7.SERVICEDN+Q7.SERVICEPROFILE
            +Q7.ROLECONTAINERDN+Q7.CONTAINERDN
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEID


2) HSJOIN: (Hash Join)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      778.169
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        2.19454e+08
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        647.617
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   778.169
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     2.19454e+08
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     647.617
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  778.169
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   649.382

    Arguments:
    ---------
    BITFLTR : (Hash Join Bit Filter used)
        FALSE
    EARLYOUT: (Early Out flag)
        LEFT
    HASHCODE: (Hash Code Size)
        24 BIT
    TEMPSIZE: (Temporary Table Page Size)
        32768

    Predicates:
    ----------
    2) Predicate used in Join
        Comparison Operator:        Equal (=)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          0.4935

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        (Q6.STATUS = Q2.$C0)


    Input Streams:
    -------------
        9) From Operator #3

            Estimated number of rows:   24859
            Number of columns:      22
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.ISOSR+Q6.INACTIVATIONDATE
            +Q6.INACTIVATEDBYUSER
            +Q6.DEPROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q6.PROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEADMINTEAM+Q6.PRIVILEGEBACKUPOWNER
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEOWNER+Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPING
            +Q6.ACCESSTYPE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEIDENTIFICATIONSOURCE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPINGTYPE+Q6.PRIVILEGETYPE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEDESCRIPTION+Q6.PRIVILEGENAME
            +Q6.SERVICEPROFILE+Q6.ROLECONTAINERDN
            +Q6.CONTAINERDN+Q6.PRIVILEGEID+Q6.SERVICEDN
            +Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME+Q6.STATUS

        11) From Operator #9

            Estimated number of rows:   2
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q2.$C0


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        12) To Operator #1

            Estimated number of rows:   24535.8
            Number of columns:      22
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q7.GROUPPROFILENAME+Q7.ISOSR
            +Q7.INACTIVATIONDATE+Q7.INACTIVATEDBYUSER
            +Q7.STATUS+Q7.DEPROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q7.PROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEADMINTEAM+Q7.PRIVILEGEBACKUPOWNER
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEOWNER+Q7.PRIVILEGEMAPPING
            +Q7.ACCESSTYPE
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEIDENTIFICATIONSOURCE
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEMAPPINGTYPE+Q7.PRIVILEGETYPE
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEDESCRIPTION+Q7.PRIVILEGENAME
            +Q7.SERVICEDN+Q7.SERVICEPROFILE
            +Q7.ROLECONTAINERDN+Q7.CONTAINERDN
            +Q7.PRIVILEGEID


3) FETCH : (Fetch)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      772.755
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        2.0417e+08
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        647.617
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   54.5714
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     1.54044e+08
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  123.283
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   649.382

    Arguments:
    ---------
    JN INPUT: (Join input leg)
        OUTER
    MAX RIDS: (Maximum RIDs per list prefetch request)
        1024
    PREFETCH: (Type of Prefetch)
        LIST
    ROWLOCK : (Row Lock intent)
        NEXT KEY SHARE
    TABLOCK : (Table Lock intent)
        INTENT SHARE
    TBISOLVL: (Table access Isolation Level)
        CURSOR STABILITY

    Predicates:
    ----------
    4) Sargable Predicate
        Comparison Operator:        In List (IN), evaluated by binary search (list sorted at run-time)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          0.20921

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        Q6.SERVICEDN IN (:?, 'ALL')

    9) Sargable Predicate
        Comparison Operator:        Not Applicable
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          0.824771

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        ((Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME IS NULL OR (Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME 
                = 'ALL')) OR (((Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME = 
                'PosAixGroupProfile') OR (Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME 
                = 'PosAixRoleProfile')) OR 
                (Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME = 
                'PosAixUserAliasProfile')))


    Input Streams:
    -------------
        7) From Operator #4

            Estimated number of rows:   30140.5
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.$RID$(A)

        8) From Object ITIMUSER.TableA

            Estimated number of rows:   144068
            Number of columns:      22
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.ISOSR+Q6.INACTIVATIONDATE
            +Q6.INACTIVATEDBYUSER
            +Q6.DEPROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q6.PROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEADMINTEAM+Q6.PRIVILEGEBACKUPOWNER
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEOWNER+Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPING
            +Q6.ACCESSTYPE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEIDENTIFICATIONSOURCE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPINGTYPE+Q6.PRIVILEGETYPE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEDESCRIPTION+Q6.PRIVILEGENAME
            +Q6.SERVICEPROFILE+Q6.ROLECONTAINERDN
            +Q6.CONTAINERDN+Q6.PRIVILEGEID+Q6.SERVICEDN
            +Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME+Q6.STATUS


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        9) To Operator #2

            Estimated number of rows:   24859
            Number of columns:      22
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.ISOSR+Q6.INACTIVATIONDATE
            +Q6.INACTIVATEDBYUSER
            +Q6.DEPROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q6.PROVISIONINGNOTIFICATION
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEADMINTEAM+Q6.PRIVILEGEBACKUPOWNER
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEOWNER+Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPING
            +Q6.ACCESSTYPE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEIDENTIFICATIONSOURCE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEMAPPINGTYPE+Q6.PRIVILEGETYPE
            +Q6.PRIVILEGEDESCRIPTION+Q6.PRIVILEGENAME
            +Q6.SERVICEPROFILE+Q6.ROLECONTAINERDN
            +Q6.CONTAINERDN+Q6.PRIVILEGEID+Q6.SERVICEDN
            +Q6.GROUPPROFILENAME+Q6.STATUS


4) RIDSCN: (Row Identifier Scan)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      115.713
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        1.05646e+08
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        28.6349
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   21.0693
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     5.94745e+07
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  115.712
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   30.4006

    Arguments:
    ---------
    NUMROWS : (Estimated number of rows)
        30141

    Input Streams:
    -------------
        3) From Operator #5

            Estimated number of rows:   6.47526
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.$RID$(A)

        6) From Operator #7

            Estimated number of rows:   30134
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.$RID$(A)


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        7) To Operator #3

            Estimated number of rows:   30140.5
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.$RID$(A)


5) SORT  : (Sort)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      7.59396
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        95860.9
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        1
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   0.0156471
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     44168.7
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  7.59396
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   2

    Arguments:
    ---------
    DUPLWARN: (Duplicates Warning flag)
        TRUE
    NUMROWS : (Estimated number of rows)
        7
    ROWWIDTH: (Estimated width of rows)
        20
    SORTKEY : (Sort Key column)
        1: Q6.$RID$(A)
    TEMPSIZE: (Temporary Table Page Size)
        32768
    UNIQUE  : (Uniqueness required flag)
        TRUE

    Input Streams:
    -------------
        2) From Operator #6

            Estimated number of rows:   6.47526
            Number of columns:      2
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.SERVICEDN(A)+Q6.STATUS(A)


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        3) To Operator #4

            Estimated number of rows:   6.47526
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.$RID$(A)


6) IXSCAN: (Index Scan)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      7.59281
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        92629.7
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        1
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   0.0156471
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     44168.7
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  7.58887
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   2

    Arguments:
    ---------
    MAXPAGES: (Maximum pages for prefetch)
        1
    PREFETCH: (Type of Prefetch)
        NONE
    ROWLOCK : (Row Lock intent)
        NONE
    SCANDIR : (Scan Direction)
        FORWARD
    TABLOCK : (Table Lock intent)
        INTENT NONE
    TBISOLVL: (Table access Isolation Level)
        CURSOR STABILITY

    Predicates:
    ----------
    7) Start Key Predicate
        Comparison Operator:        Equal (=)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          4.49458e-05

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        (Q6.SERVICEDN = :?)

    7) Stop Key Predicate
        Comparison Operator:        Equal (=)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          4.49458e-05

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        (Q6.SERVICEDN = :?)


    Input Streams:
    -------------
        1) From Object ITIMUSER.SVCDN_STATUS

            Estimated number of rows:   144068
            Number of columns:      3
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.SERVICEDN(A)+Q6.STATUS(A)+Q6.$RID$


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        2) To Operator #5

            Estimated number of rows:   6.47526
            Number of columns:      2
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.SERVICEDN(A)+Q6.STATUS(A)


7) SORT  : (Sort)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      108.119
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        1.05551e+08
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        27.6349
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   18.3837
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     5.18936e+07
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  108.119
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   28.4006

    Arguments:
    ---------
    DUPLWARN: (Duplicates Warning flag)
        TRUE
    NUMROWS : (Estimated number of rows)
        30134
    ROWWIDTH: (Estimated width of rows)
        20
    SORTKEY : (Sort Key column)
        1: Q6.$RID$(A)
    TEMPSIZE: (Temporary Table Page Size)
        32768
    UNIQUE  : (Uniqueness required flag)
        TRUE

    Input Streams:
    -------------
        5) From Operator #8

            Estimated number of rows:   30134
            Number of columns:      2
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.SERVICEDN(A)+Q6.STATUS(A)


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        6) To Operator #4

            Estimated number of rows:   30134
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.$RID$(A)


8) IXSCAN: (Index Scan)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      89.201
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        5.21489e+07
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        27.6349
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   18.3837
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     5.18936e+07
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  7.58887
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   28.4006

    Arguments:
    ---------
    MAXPAGES: (Maximum pages for prefetch)
        27
    PREFETCH: (Type of Prefetch)
        SEQUENTIAL
    ROWLOCK : (Row Lock intent)
        NONE
    SCANDIR : (Scan Direction)
        FORWARD
    TABLOCK : (Table Lock intent)
        INTENT NONE
    TBISOLVL: (Table access Isolation Level)
        CURSOR STABILITY

    Predicates:
    ----------
    8) Start Key Predicate
        Comparison Operator:        Equal (=)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          0.209165

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        (Q6.SERVICEDN = 'ALL')

    8) Stop Key Predicate
        Comparison Operator:        Equal (=)
        Subquery Input Required:    No
        Filter Factor:          0.209165

        Predicate Text:
        --------------
        (Q6.SERVICEDN = 'ALL')


    Input Streams:
    -------------
        4) From Object ITIMUSER.SVCDN_STATUS

            Estimated number of rows:   144068
            Number of columns:      3
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.SERVICEDN(A)+Q6.STATUS(A)+Q6.$RID$


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        5) To Operator #7

            Estimated number of rows:   30134
            Number of columns:      2
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q6.SERVICEDN(A)+Q6.STATUS(A)


9) TBSCAN: (Table Scan)
    Cumulative Total Cost:      5.31387e-05
    Cumulative CPU Cost:        150
    Cumulative I/O Cost:        0
    Cumulative Re-Total Cost:   5.31387e-05
    Cumulative Re-CPU Cost:     150
    Cumulative Re-I/O Cost:     0
    Cumulative First Row Cost:  3.18832e-05
    Estimated Bufferpool Buffers:   0

    Arguments:
    ---------
    GENRVALS: (GENROW IN List values)
        VALUES ('A', 'P')
    JN INPUT: (Join input leg)
        INNER
    MAXPAGES: (Maximum pages for prefetch)
        ALL
    PREFETCH: (Type of Prefetch)
        NONE
    ROWLOCK : (Row Lock intent)
        NEXT KEY SHARE
    SCANDIR : (Scan Direction)
        FORWARD
    TABLOCK : (Table Lock intent)
        INTENT SHARE
    TBISOLVL: (Table access Isolation Level)
        CURSOR STABILITY

    Input Streams:
    -------------
        10) From Object SYSIBM.GENROW

            Estimated number of rows:   2
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q1.NUMB


    Output Streams:
    --------------
        11) To Operator #2

            Estimated number of rows:   2
            Number of columns:      1
            Subquery predicate ID:      Not Applicable

            Column Names:
            ------------
            +Q2.$C0
```

### Objects Used in Access Plan:

```
Schema: ITIMUSER
Name:   SVCDN_STATUS
Type:   Index
        Time of creation:       2014-07-04-07.27.27.866382
        Last statistics update:     2014-07-04-09.37.29.120054
        Number of columns:      2
        Number of rows:         144068
        Width of rows:          -1
        Number of buffer pool pages:    2409
        Distinct row values:        No
        Tablespace name:        ENROLE_DATA       
        Tablespace overhead:        7.500000
        Tablespace transfer rate:   0.060000
        Source for statistics:      Single Node
        Prefetch page count:        32
        Container extent page count:    32
        Index clustering statistic:     94.000000
        Index leaf pages:       131
        Index tree levels:      2
        Index full key cardinality:     26559
        Index first key cardinality:    22249
        Index first 2 keys cardinality: 26559
        Index first 3 keys cardinality: -1
        Index first 4 keys cardinality: -1
        Index sequential pages:     130
        Index page density:         99
        Index avg sequential pages:     130
        Index avg gap between sequences:0
        Index avg random pages:     0
        Fetch avg sequential pages:     -1
        Fetch avg gap between sequences:-1
        Fetch avg random pages:     -1
        Index RID count:        144068
        Index deleted RID count:    0
        Index empty leaf pages:     0
        Base Table Schema:      ITIMUSER
        Base Table Name:        TableA
        Columns in index:
            SERVICEDN(A)
            STATUS(A)

Schema: ITIMUSER
Name:   TableA
Type:   Table
        Time of creation:       2012-02-24-15.04.35.829088
        Last statistics update:     2014-07-04-09.37.29.120054
        Number of columns:      23
        Number of rows:         144068
        Width of rows:          542
        Number of buffer pool pages:    2409
        Number of data partitions:  1
        Distinct row values:        No
        Tablespace name:        ENROLE_DATA       
        Tablespace overhead:        7.500000
        Tablespace transfer rate:   0.060000
        Source for statistics:      Single Node
        Prefetch page count:        32
        Container extent page count:    32
        Table overflow record count:    0
        Table Active Blocks:        -1
        Average Row Compression Ratio:  0
        Percentage Rows Compressed:     0
        Average Compressed Row Size:    0

Schema: SYSIBM  
Name:   GENROW
Type:   Table Function
        Time of creation:
        Last statistics update:
        Number of columns:      1
        Number of rows:         2
        Width of rows:          11
        Number of buffer pool pages:    -1
        Distinct row values:        No
        Source for statistics:      Single Node
```

**Note :** DB2 LUW 9.5 on AIX.

Comment: I'd try an index on `ITIMUSER (SERVICEDN, GROUPPROFILENAME, STATUS)`. However, the predicate involving `GROUPPROFILENAME` is estimated to have the filter factor of 0.8, which basically means you'll have 80% of the table matching, so you'll still end up reading a lot of rows. Is the estimated size of the result set (24.5K rows) close to reality?

Comment: The sort heap is about 1500 pages, which is pretty small. Do you see sort overflow(s) on this statement? If so, try doubling the sort heap until you get rid of them.

Comment: `IN(...)` operators tend to generate the same plan steps as a series of `OR`s (as they're usually equivalent).  You might be able to use a virtual table of some sort (ie a CTE or other `VALUES(...)` table reference) so that you could `JOIN` to it, but that `null` condition is going to throw things off (and I'm not sure how much it would help if you're selecting 80% of rows).

Comment: @mustaccio :Yes I am still checking that query needs that much amount of rows or not. Its a logic written by someone else. Anyways thanks for help and please suggest if you find anything.

Comment: The question isn't whether you need that many rows; the question is whether the actual number of rows returned is close to what the optimizer thinks it would (24.5K).

Comment: Yes, I analyzed the application logs and in reality it is fetching around 25K rows i.e. close to optimizer generated no. of rows.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried **db2advis** (db2advisor utility) ... it will sugesst missing indexes.

as mustaccio suggested, i will also try to create an index on these fields: SERVICEDN, GROUPPROFILENAME and STATUS.

how many rows do you expect ... the query looks a little bit strange to me, to many 'or' conditions.

did you tried to **REORG** / **RUNSTATS** the table ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried Reorg,runstats as well as db2advis. It is suggesting index on servicedn and status so I applied that index also. still no success.